# scroll down to specific div id on page from inside a php redirect function

Tags: php, html, redirect

I have a redirect function which works, and inside it I'm using a variable that tells it where to link to.

```
redirect_to($url);
```

For a couple times I need to use this function, however, I want it scroll down to a certain div id on the page, which I think is usually something like:

```
<a href="#comments">scroll to comments</a>
```

I just don't know the proper way to combine that with the php function I'm using above. Everything I've tried just gives me a syntax error.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have an anchor defined try:

```
$anchor = '#comments';
redirect_to("{$url}{$anchor}");
```

Answer (score 0):

Give it anchor an id then ur redirect will be 'header("url#idname")

Comment: Please explain how this provides an additional insight to the existing, much older, upvoted and accepted answer. Please be a little more verbose with your explanation, the current phrasing is extremely brief, to the point of being unclear. Just for readability sake, please use existing English words (i.e. not "ur"). Have a look here for formatting hints ( https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help ). Consider using a clearer grammar, i.e. either "Give it an anchor and an id. Then ..." or "Give its anchor an id. Then ...".  With these you could improve the impression of respecting other users.